# How to make a table (Jtable) not editable

Tags: java, swing, unicode, jtable

I've been working with some Japanese Characters, I've used unicode but I've been reading and reading how to make a JTable not editable, and still can't figure it out how to get it into my code... maybe I'm tired from 5 days of research... that's why I come to you.

Here's the code I've been using:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class hiragana extends JFrame {
    hiragana() {

        String header [] = {" ","A","I","U","E","O"};
        String data [][]= {
            {" ", "\u3042", "\u3044", "\u3046", "\u3048", "\u304A"},
            {"K", "\u304b", "\u304d", "\u304f", "\u3051", "\u3053"},
            {"S", "\u3055", "\u3057", "\u3059", "\u305b", "\u305d"},
            {"T", "\u305f", "\u3061", "\u3064", "\u3066", "\u3068"},
            {"N", "\u306a", "\u306b", "\u306c", "\u306d", "\u306e"},
            {"H", "\u306f", "\u3072", "\u3075", "\u3078", "\u307b"},
            {"M", "\u307e", "\u307f", "\u3080", "\u3081", "\u3082"},
            {"Y", "\u3084", " ","\u3086", " ", "\u3088"},
            {"R", "\u3089", "\u308a", "\u308b", "\u308c", "\u308d"},
            {"W", "\u308f", " ", " ", " ", "\u3092"},
            {"N \'", " ", " ", "\u3093", " ", " "}
        };

        JTable table = new JTable(data, header);
        table.setFont(new Font("Adobe Fangsong Std R",Font.BOLD,20));
        table.setRowHeight(table.getRowHeight()+30);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(scrollPane);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(250,700);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Here is the output,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a suitable table model that can return `false` when `TableModel#isCellEditable(int row, int column)` is called.

By default, the `DefaultTableModel` will return true.

Take a look at [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 1):

Control whether or not a cell is editable through the [`TableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#isCellEditable%28int,%20int%29).  Define your own `TableModel` class by extending [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html).