# Button in JTable cell not click-able

Tags: java, swing, applet, jtable, jbutton

I have a jtable with the first column having jbuttons. However when i try to click the button nothing happens. Hovering over the button also doesn't change it's shade to show that it's clickable..

I am running this from within a Java Applet.

I am using the Button Column Class from here:
http://www.camick.com/java/source/ButtonColumn.java

and here is the code i inserted myself

```
tablemodel = new DefaultTableModel();
//PnlThinClientTable.COLUMNS is an array of strings with the titles of the columns
tablemodel.setColumnIdentifiers(PnlThinClientTable.COLUMNS);
JTable table = new JTable(tablemodel);


table.setEnabled(false);
table.setDefaultRenderer(table.getColumnClass(5), new CustomTblCellRenderer());
table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

Action wakeUpRow = new AbstractAction() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        JTable table = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int modelRow = Integer.valueOf( e.getActionCommand() );         
        System.out.println("Action Performed");
    }
};
// Main.hm_language.get(Language.WAKE_ON_LAN) returns the title of the column i'm interested in
table.getColumn(Main.hm_language.get(Language.WAKE_ON_LAN)).setCellRenderer(new ButtonColumn(table,wakeUpRow,0));
table.getColumn(Main.hm_language.get(Language.WAKE_ON_LAN)).setCellEditor(new ButtonColumn(table, wakeUpRow, 0));
```

Comment: Your problem in next line `table.setEnabled(false);`. That make your `JTable` disabled, because of you cant use `JButton` in your column.

Comment: thank you ! Is there a way to only enable the chosen column however, as i do not want the other columns to be editable

Comment: Yes, you can. Override `isCellEditable(int row, int column)` method of `DefaultTableModel`

Comment: managed to fix it. @override public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col). If you post an answer i'll rate it up. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @alex2410 for the solution

I had to make sure the cell was Editable

this can be done by either extending the Table upon declaration and overriding the isCellEditable(int row, int col): boolean  method,
or in my case I overrode isCellEditable(EventObject e):boolean in the Cell Editor which I apply to the column,

hence the snippet within the Cell Editor I am using would be

```
@Override
public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject e){
    return true;
}
```

This is as all cells to which the editor is applied need to be editable, as they are all buttons in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to the comment of "how to make 1st column editable" here's how

```
class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway I leave [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) Documentation in case it's needed.

And also this post that could help: [How to make a table (Jtable) not editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469100/how-to-make-a-table-jtable-not-editable)